# Operator Overloading in Racket / Scheme

Tags: module, scheme, overloading, racket

I am having some trouble here, and hopefully you guys can help.

Basically, what I am trying to do is overload the + sign in racket so that it will add two vectors instead of two numbers. Also, I want to keep the old + operator so that we can still use it. I know this is supposed to work in scheme, so I was told I needed to use module* to do it in racket. I am still not entirely sure how it all works.

Here is what I have so far:

```
#lang racket

(module* fun scheme/base 
  (define old+ +) 
  (define + new+)

  (define (new+ x y)
    (cond ((and (vector? x) (vector? y))
           (quatplus x y))
          (else (old+ x y))))

  (define (quatplus x y)
    (let ((z (make-vector 4)))
      (vector-set! z 0 (old+ (vector-ref x 0) (vector-ref y 0)))
      (vector-set! z 1 (old+ (vector-ref x 1) (vector-ref y 1)))
      (vector-set! z 2 (old+ (vector-ref x 2) (vector-ref y 2)))
      (vector-set! z 3 (old+ (vector-ref x 3) (vector-ref y 3)))
      z)))
```

But it doesn't seem to do anything at all. If anyone knows anything about this I would be very appreciative.

Thank you.

Comment: As a warning, do not deface your questions. If you do this again, I will lock the question and may suspend your account.

Comment: what's defacing a question?

Comment: Defacing means significantly editing a post to change its meaning.  In this case (http://stackoverflow.com/posts/21768408/revisions) the OP tried to obfuscate the entire post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How I would do this is to use the `except-in` and `rename-in` specs for `require`:

```
#lang racket/base

(require (except-in racket + -)
         (rename-in racket [+ old+] [- old-]))

(define (+ x y)
  (cond [(and (vector? x) (vector? y))
         (quatplus x y)]
        [else (old+ x y)]))

(define (quatplus x y)
  (vector  (+ (vector-ref x 0) (vector-ref y 0))
           (+ (vector-ref x 1) (vector-ref y 1))
           (+ (vector-ref x 2) (vector-ref y 2))
           (+ (vector-ref x 3) (vector-ref y 3))))

(+ (vector 1 2 3 4) (vector 1 2 3 4))
;; => #(2 4 6 8)
```

You could also use `prefix-in` with `only-in`, which would be more convenient if you had many such functions to rename:

```
(require (except-in racket + -)
         (prefix-in old (only-in racket + -)))
```

A few points:

- I had `quatplus` simply return a new immutable vector (instead of using `make-vector` and `set!`). It's simpler and probably faster.
- Racket's `+` accepts any number of arguments. Maybe yours should?
- As written, your new `+` will fail for the combination of a non-`vector` and a `vector`. You probably want to fix that:

  ```
  (+ 1 (vector 1 2 3 4))
  ; +: contract violation
  ;   expected: number?
  ;   given: '#(1 2 3 4)
  ;   argument position: 1st
  ;   other arguments...:
  ;    1
  ```

Answer (score 3):

You can use Scheme encapsulation to accomplish your needs as:

```
(import (rename (rnrs) (+ numeric+)))

(define +
  (let ((vector+ (lambda (v1 v2) (vector-map numeric+ v1 v2)))
        (list+   (lambda (l1 l2) (map        numeric+ l1 l2)))
        ;; … 
        )
   (lambda (a b)
     (cond ((and (vector? a) (vector? b)) (vector+ a b))
           ((and (list?   a) (list?   b)) (list+   a b))
           ;; …
           (else (numeric+ a b))))))
```

and if you wanted to work the addition to any depth, this should work:

```
(define +
  (letrec ((vector+ (lambda (v1 v2) (vector-map any+ v1 v2)))
           (list+   (lambda (l1 l2) (map        any+ l1 l2)))
           (any+    (lambda (a b)
                      (cond ((and (vector? a) (vector? b)) (vector+ a b))
                            ((and (list?   a) (list?   b)) (list+   a b))
                            ;; …
                            (else (numeric+ a b))))))
     any+))
```

See:

```
> (+ (vector (list 1 2) 3) (vector (list 11 12) 13))
#((12 14) 16)
```